# Object not found Error: loop that will find the cell with the same value in another sheet, select the offset of the new found cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create some vba that will do a loop on cells in a column on sheet 1, then check if the cell is apparent on sheet 2, if it is then i want the offset of the sheet 2 value pasted next to the original sheet 1 value. I get the error object required on the cell function or value to find.

```
Sub findValue()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToFind

For Each cell In Range("h2:h8")
cell.Select
cell = ActiveCell
MsgBox (cell)

valueToFind = ActiveCell
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A13")

For Each xlCell In xlRange


    If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
        MsgBox (xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
  valueToFind.Offset(0, 2).Value = xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

    End If
Next xlCell
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff that looks a little strange (according to what is valid syntax) in your code, so I re-wrote an example below.

```
Sub getOffsetValue()

    Dim origWS as Worksheet
    Dim dataWS as Worksheet

    Set origWS = Worksheets("original") 'change as needed
    Set dataWS = Worksheets("DATA")

    Dim checkCell as Range

    For each checkCell in origWS.Range("H2:H8")

        Dim foundIt as Range
        Set foundIt = dataws.Range("A1:A13").Find(checkCell.Value)

        If Not foundIt is Nothing then

            MsgBox foundIt.Offset(0, 1).Value
            checkCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = foundIt.Offset(0, 1).Value

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500 - Fair point. I made it a community wiki. Please add additional context as you see fit. At the moment, i do not have time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: I needed to add 'set' to the first cell loop